# A Regex positive lookahead

Tags: regex

I wanna get a substring from another string  with RegExp.

The source: `\\abc\\\$`
The pattern: `/\\+(?=\$)$/`
Expected result: `\\\`

So I'm expecting to get the result in the end of the string, but the positive lookahead doesn't work as I want. Without the (?=) part it works but gives me the `$` symbol => `\\\$` but I don't need it.

What's the problem here?
Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to put the `$` end of the line inside the lookahead as lookaheads don't consume characters. They just check if the previous token is followed by the token in the lookahead.

```
/\\+(?=\$$)/
```

[**DEMO**](https://regex101.com/r/oC5kK2/2)

Answer (score 3):

The problem is that a look ahead is a zero width assertion. The `(?=\$)` part of the expression doesn't 'consume' a character. So the expression looks for the end of the string after your look ahead but finds the `$` character.

use `/\\+(?=\$$)/` instead

Answer (score 0):

You probably meant to use a capturing group, too; and are you sure about the second $?

Try this (if the string must be `$` terminated):

```
/(\\+)(?=\$$)/
```

or this (if the $ can occur anywhere in the string):

```
/(\\+)(?=\$)/
```

Answer (score 0):

Your regex:

`\\+(?=\$)$`

does the following:

- Match the backslash character between 1 and unlimmited times ... `\\+`
- Positive lookahead of match the character $ ... `(?=\$)`
- Assert the position is at the end of the line. `$`

---

The corrected regex is:

`\\+(?=\$$)`

This regex does:

- Match the backslash character between 1 and unlimmited times ... `\\+`
- Positive lookahead of match the character $ and assert it's on the end of the line ... `(?=\$$)`

The main problem is, that the positive lookahead doesn't consume a character.
It's a zero-length assertion like the end of the line.
So you have to assert inside the positive lookahead, that the $ character is at the end of the line.